# Sql how to remove duplicate records with merging values?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to remove duplicate records with merging values?

I have the table with id (integer pm key), val1 (text), val2 (text).

Current situation:

```
------------------

 id  val1    val2

 1.  john     sam
 2.  larry    tom
 3.  john     joe
```

I want to have:

```
---------------

 id  val1    val2

 1.  john     sam, joe
 2.  larry    tom
...
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this, you can't `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in one single query. However, you can do this as two `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries like so:

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT val1, GROUP_CONCAT(val2 SEPARATOR ',') Val2
  FROM Table1
  GROUP BY val1
) t2 ON t1.val1 = t2.val1
SET t1.val2 = t2.val2;

DELETE t
FROM table1 t
WHERE id NOT IN
(
  SELECT ID
  FROM
  (
    SELECT MIN(ID) id, val1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY val1
   ) sub
 );
```

This will make the changes you want.

**Note that:** You have to put these two queries in one [***TRANSACTION***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html).

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da145/1)

These two queries will make your table looks like:

```
| ID |  VAL1 |    VAL2 |
------------------------
|  1 |  john | sam,joe |
|  2 | larry |     tom |
```

Comment: Thank you very much it seems that this is working for my code... Obviously it is taking some time because I have about 40 thousand records in my db in utf8...

Comment: I had 40000 records and as a result about 8000 duplicated records were removed and merged.  It took about 34 minutes (db size were almost 4 MB in UTF8). Thank you again.

Comment: @Johny - Sorry for my late response. I don't know really other solutions for this. But this is supposed to be done only one time. Right? So this might be acceptable. You can also begin a new question on this performance optimisation issue.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sketch of idea:

1) Create temporary table like:

```
select val1, min(id) min_id, group_concat(val2) val2
from table
group by val1
```

2) Update val2 for records with id = temp.min_id

3) Remove record where val1 = temp.val1 and id != min_id

Answer (score 1):

u can use this

```
   SELECT val1, GROUP_CONCAT(val2 SEPARATOR ',') val2  FROM your_table t1
   INNER JOIN your_table t2 ON  t2.id = t1.id

     WHERE t2.val1 = t1.val1

  GROUP BY  t1.val1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have answers how to make what you are asking for. I wonder if you realy want to merge values this way? Don't you need new table?

Main table

```
id  val1    

1.  john    
2.  larry
```

New table:

```
idMain val2

1 sam
1 joe
2 tom
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I think your answer is correct.  But I do not new table for now. Because Mahmoud Gamal's answer worked 100 percent for my code.